# Flutter hot reload in android studio restarting the app and not hot reloading

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem in Flutter 3.10.5
when I use hot reload it restarts the application

I don't want what's the problem , I used bloc

this is the main dart

```
void main() async {
  configureDependencies();
  Bloc.observer = AppBlocObserver();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  AppRouter get _routerConfig => getIt.get<AppRouter>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: MaterialApp.router(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        routerConfig: _routerConfig,
        localizationsDelegates: const [
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: const [
          Locale('ar'), // Arabic
          Locale('en'), // English
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```